# extract values from DataTable with single row

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, datarow

How to extract the values from data table having single row and assign to asp labels.

```
private void GetUser(string userId)
{
    dbr.SelectString = "select name, gender,  address, contactno from userInfo where id = = '" + userId + "' --"; // return single row
    DataTable dt = dbr.GetTable();
    //DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];
    // how to retrieve the fields from the data table.
    //lbl_name = name.ToString();
    //lbl_gender = gender.ToString();
    //lbl_contact = contactno.ToString();
}
```

I thought of using `foreach` loop but the datatable contains only single row. **How can I pass empty string in the case of NULL cells.** Also, can I extract the values from datatable via **list**?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
private void GetUser(string userId)
{
    dbr.SelectString = "select name, gender,  address, contactno from userInfo where id = = '" + userId + "' --"; // return single row
    DataTable dt = dbr.GetTable();
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) 
    {
        DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];

        lbl_name = row["name"].ToString();
        lbl_gender = row["gender"].ToString();
        lbl_contact = row["contactno"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply. can I convert this data table to list and retrieve values. Which will be more preferably? Please can you explain.

Comment: @user4221591, which kind of list? dataTable contains 1 row, create a single object of custom type

Answer (score 3):

Simply in one line

```
dbr.SelectString = "select name, gender,  address, contactno from userInfo where id = = '" + userId + "' --"; 
DataTable DataTable_Values= dbr.GetTable(); 
lbl_name =  DataTable_Values.Rows[0].Field<string>("name");
lbl_gender =  DataTable_Values.Rows[0].Field<int>("gender");
lbl_contact =  DataTable_Values.Rows[0].Field<int>("contact")
```

Answer (score 0):

To get an list of all Rows, you need a Class

```
  class Lbl()
            {
                public string Name {get; set;}
                public string Gender {get; set;}
                public string Contact {get; set;}
            }
```

Fill the class:

```
 List<Lbl> list = new List<Lbl>();
            foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                Lbl lbl = new Lbl();
                lbl.Name = row["name"].ToString();
                lbl.Gender = row["gender"].ToString();
                lbl.Contact = row["contactno"].ToString();

                list.add(lbl);
            }
```

Comment: how to handle if the columns return NULL values. Please can you share.

Comment: object value = row["name"];
    if (!value == DBNull.Value)
    {
    }
    else    {
    }

Comment: in MsSQL you can use the IsNull-Method: SELECT ISNULL(name,'') AS name

Comment: @user4221591, value of dataRow cell can never be null. NULL from db will be converted into DbNull.Value

Answer (score 0):

its quite late but I think what you are looking for is the below code, this Datatable is the result of a query. That DT is then being parsed with all its rows and columns as a string.

```
DataTable dt = Execute_Query(Connection, query);
            if (dt != null)
            {
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    J = dt.Rows.Count;

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++) 
                        {
                            sb.Append(dt.Rows[i][j] + ",");
                        }
                        sb.Append("\n");
                    }

                    Logger.Info(sb.ToString());
                }
            }
```